# I got an attribute error while trying to use a decorator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclass, python-decorators

i got an attribute error in the code below
this is the result

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/fortu/PycharmProjects/telusko.py/inheritance.py", line 18, in 
p1.name()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

```
class Church:

    church = 'RCCG'

    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

    @classmethod
    def get_church(cls):
        return cls.church

    def name(self):
        print(f'{self.fname}, {self.lname}, member of ')

p = Church('John','Doe')
p1 = p.get_church()
p1.name()
```

Comment: Your `get_church` returns a string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to print fname lname plus the church name which is RCCG in one line

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_church` method returns a `string` which is `RCCG` which is assigned to `p1`. That's why you're getting `AttributeError` when you invoke `p1.name()`.

```py
p1 = p.get_church() # p1 value is RCCG

# above is equivalent to
p1 = p.church

# now when you do this `p1.name()` it's equivalent to doing
"RCCG".name() # this is where you'll get an error
```

---

> im trying to print fname lname plus the church name which is RCCG in one line

You have to make changes on your `name` method to include `self.church`.

```
def name(self):
    print(f'{self.fname}, {self.lname}, member of {self.church}')
```

then call `name` method from `p`.

```py
p = Church('John','Doe')
p.name()
```